# Does raspberry pi 4 support face_recognition faster rate than raspberry pi 3 B+?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, raspberry-pi3, face-recognition, raspberry-pi4

I have install the face_recognition package in raspberry pi 3+( raspian stretch os ) due to RAM the time taking to recognize the face is high. Does raspberry pi 4 support faster rate than RPI 3 B+ ???